# number of subgroups in $S_5$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I want to solve the following problem:

> Find the number of subgroups in $S_5$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

First of all, from Cayley's theorem, I know

> Every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_G$.

The element in $S_5$ with order $5$ is $(1,2,3,4,5)$ so my guess was $\mathbb{Z}_5 = < (1,2,3,4,5)>$

But having trouble understanding the number of groups.

[Wikipedia](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S5) states the total number of the subgroup is $6$, but how to count properly?

Comment: In which part it says that the number of subgroups is $6$? I don't see it.

Comment: @azif00: Next to last column in [this table](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S5#Table_classifying_subgroups_up_to_automorphisms); the entry for subgroups isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5$ is near the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the copies of $\Bbb Z_5$ is generated by a cyclic permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. For instance, one is generated by $p=(1,2,3,4,5)$ and has $p^2=(1,3,5,2,4)$, $p^3=(1,4,2,5,3)$, $p^4=(1,5,4,3,2)$, and $p^5=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$ as its other four elements.

There are $4!$ such permutations (why?), and each of these groups contains $4$ of them. The only element that two of these groups can have in common is the identity, $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$, so there must be $\frac{4!}4=3!=6$ of these groups.

Comment: I guess 4! because of $(5-1)!$ ( I mean cyclic permutations of 5 elements) am I right?

Comment: @phy_math: Yes, that’s right.