# number of subgroup in $S_n$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

This is a generalization of my previous question in [number of subgroups in $S_5$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039041/number-of-subgroups-in-s-5-which-are-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-5)

> I want to find the number of subgroups in $S_n$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Inspired by @Brian M. Scott, I write my proposal as follow:

Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic, I guess $p=\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots, n\}$ and $p, p^2, p^3, \cdots, p^n=e$.

Letting $p=(1,2,3,\cdots, n)$ and since it is cyclic there are $(n-1)!$ case of permutations. So my guess is $\frac{(n-1)!}{n-1} = (n-2)!$

Am I right?  Is there any other way to find the number of subgroups?

Comment: Your notation is very confusing: what exactly is $p$? First you have $p = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, so it's a set. Then you raise that set to various powers: $p, p^2, p^3, \ldots$. Finally, you redefine $p$ as an $n$-tuple $(1, \ldots, n)$. What does this mean?

Comment: @Théophile I guess OP means a cycle with length $n$. More commonly denoted by $(a_1\, a_2\, a_3\dots a_n)$.

Comment: Related [to this more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039067/how-to-find-the-subgroups-of-s-n-which-are-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-l), also asked by you. You should see that there are more than just $n$-cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Powers of $n$-cycles $(123\dots n)$ are not $n$-cycles unless the power is prime to the order.  And there are more elments of order $n$ than just an $n$-cycle.

Examples:

- $n=4$: There are indeed $3!=6$ 4-cycles, but each $C_4$ only contains 2 of them.
- $n=6$: cycletypes (6) and (2,3).  There are $5!=120$ cycletype (6) and another $\binom{6}{3,2,1}$ cycletype (2,3).  Each $C_6$ contains $\phi(6)=2$ generators.
- $n=8,9$ similar to $n=4$.
- $n=10$: cycletypes (10), (2,5), (2,2,5) are all order 10.  I'll leave you to count it.
- $n=12$: I'll leave you to list the cycletypes and count.

Comment: While this identifies the error in OP's solution, it doesn't answer the problem. IMHO, it should more be of a comment.